# When terminating a process is it possible to delete a file?

Tags: c, windows, file-io

I would need to write a **Windows C application** which creates a file, and this file needs to be deleted when the application is terminated(both in case of graceful termination or forced kill).

One more requirement is user should also be able to open this file in Read-only mode(may be using the Notepad). Basically this would be read in Java(i.e DocumentBuilder::parse)

I have written the following code

```
   HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("d:\\test.xml",                
                   GENERIC_WRITE,          
                   FILE_SHARE_READ,                      
                   NULL,                   
                   CREATE_ALWAYS,             
                   FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE,  
                   NULL);
```

When I open the file(i.e test.xml) in Notepad.exe, I get an error saying "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".

However, following code works fine

```
   HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("d:\\test.xml",                
                   GENERIC_WRITE,          
                   FILE_SHARE_READ,                      
                   NULL,                   
                   CREATE_ALWAYS,             
                   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                   NULL);
```

But the problem is, it does not delete the file(i.e when the application is killed).

Any help is appreciated.

In case you could suggest an approach which works both on windows and Unix, that would be great(e.g. using the boost libraries).

Comment: You say you're writing a C application, but your question is tagged as C++. Clarify.

Comment: Create the file.  Close it.  Open it again with the required flags.  As for deleting the file upon forced process termination, (Task manager or kill -9), it cannot be done.  Can you not get away with deleting the file upon process startup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx#FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE) says:

> The file is to be deleted immediately after all of its handles are
>   closed, which includes the specified handle and any other open or
>   duplicated handles.
>
> If there are existing open handles to a file, the call fails unless
>   they were all opened with the FILE_SHARE_DELETE share mode.
>
> Subsequent open requests for the file fail, unless the
>   FILE_SHARE_DELETE share mode is specified.

So, you need to arrange that `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` is passed by any process that opens the file.

Answer (score 2):

This is from our codebase: (the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24449152/321013) has the link to the docs)

`FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` will also *block readers*, unless *they specify* `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`.

```
return ::CreateFile(
    filePath, 
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, // reading and writing
    FILE_SHARE_READ, // Note: FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE will also block readers, unless they specify FILE_SHARE_DELETE 
    /*Security:*/NULL, 
    CREATE_NEW, // only create if does not exist
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY | // optimize access for temporary file
    FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE, // delete once the last handle has been closed
    NULL);
```

So it seems you are out of luck(*) with standard applications, since (according to the wisdom of my past self) the *reader* needs to also pass `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`.

---

(*) Most files can be deleted when they are open in a text editor, but I *believe* this is because these editors simply close the file handle once they have read the content. You could check the popular free ones if they offer a `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the acces level of this file:
 `if(!_tacces(path, 06) //exit application`.

More information abou _tacces: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w06ktdy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could create a helper process that tracks the main process handle and upon (any) main process termination tries to delete the file. If the file is opened in a non shared manner (by notepad or whomever) this probably cannot be done either way.